# Configure the user and group for volumes on Linux docker containers with a Windows host

Tags: docker

I'm working with an Ubuntu based docker container, using a Windows 10 host.  I'm mapping a directory through to the docker container, which works fine.  However since the file permissions in Windows are very different to the ones used in Linux, the docker daemon sets some default permissions on the volumes.  It seems to set the following:

- user: `root`
- group: `root`
- directories: `drwxrwxrwx`
- files: `-rwxr-xr-x`

These are reasonable defaults, I was wondering if it is possible to specify alternative values for these defaults?  Through any or all of the following:

- globally through docker daemon settings
- docker/docker-compose arguments
- docker-compose.yml directives

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the [User](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user) directive on your Dockerfile to manage the user that will execute the next commands (Entrypoint/CMD included).

For the permissions, you can use the [RUN](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run) directive and run a chmod command on specific files that you want.

Note that only USER directive (from the ones I shared) can use env variables according to [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#environment-replacement).

Comment: This doesn't answer my specific question.  You are correct in what you've written, but I want to know how to override the default permissions given to a volume in a linux container that points to a folder on the Windows host.